# Blazor File Upload IFormFile

Tags: asyncfileupload

I am using Blazor Wasm, and I want to uplaod a pdf or jpeg file to server.

Please dont share the server side code, all examples explains server side. But I need to get a client example.

Because, I want to upload media file with some date. I will use multipart/form-data, but I can not assign my file to IFormFile.

How I can assign a file/filestream to IFormFile?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I don't think that there is any native Blazor wasm components for uploading files. It exists a lot of file upload components that uses JSInterop. Among the one's that I've tried is [Radzen fileupload](https://www.radzen.com/documentation/upload-files-dotnetcore/), [Steve Sandersons (one of the developers behind blazor) fileupload](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/) and [MatBlazor fileupload](https://www.matblazor.com/FileUpload).

However, currently there is some memory issues in Mono, namely the underlying development platform that Blazor runs on. This means that Blazor only can manage files up to ~5-6 mb. Therefore I advice you to use a Blazor Components that strictly uses javascript to post the file to the server, such as Radzen fileupload.

Here is an example of the client-side fileupload using MatBlazor (since this is the one I have in hand atm):

```
     <div class="p-2">
                <MatFileUpload OnChange="AddFile" class="form-container" Label="Upload File"></MatFileUpload>
                </div>

@code
 {

    private async Task AddFile(IMatFileUploadEntry[] files)
    {
        var file = files.FirstOrDefault();
                if (file != null)
                {
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    await file.WriteToStreamAsync(ms);
                    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent 
                     {
                        { new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer()), 
                          "\"uploadFile\"", 
                          file.Name 
                        }
                    };
                    await client.PostAsync("uploadFile", content);
                }
    }
}
```